# Cell validation for react data table

Tags: reactjs, datatable, datagrid, react-table-v6

I want to have the required field validation for a custom cell, i have in my data table. With the getprops i am able to style the cell but how can i display like a helper text or error for that cell? Is there any example?

Example:

```
const columns = [
  {
    Header: 'Things to Do',
    accessor: 'item',
    getProps: (rowInfo) => {
      return {
        style: {
            backgroundColor: rowInfo && rowInfo.row.item === 'Do a thing' ? 'red' : null,
        },
      }
    }
  },
  {
    Header: '2020-04-01',
    accessor: 'date.2020-04-01',
    getProps: (rowInfo) => {
      return {
        style: {
          backgroundColor: rowInfo && rowInfo.row['date.2020-04-01'] === 'Y' ? 'red' : null,
        },
      }
    }
  },
```